Is it possible that one estimator performs better than others when sample size $n$ is small but performs worse than others when $n$ is large?
Are there any examples that one estimator performs better than others when sample size $n$ is small but performs worse than others when $n$ is large?

@StephanKolassa Thanks! I made some modifications to be clear.


Do you have a preferred measure of "performs better"? 2. Would an example with two estimators which swap their performance as sample size increases suffice as a positive example? Or do you require "others" to have more than one member in the set?


Of course.  Simply pick a bad estimator $b$ and a good estimator $g$, then define two new estimators by selecting $b$ when $n\lt 1000$ and $g$ otherwise (on the one hand) and selecting $g$ when $n\lt 1000$ and $b$ otherwise (on the other hand).  This construction is universal: it works no matter what you mean by "performs better" (cc @Glen_b).

@Glen_b Thanks! 1. I want to use MSE to measure their performance. 2. Yes, it is possitive! P.S. Actually I'm expecting a very 'extreme' example like that the estimator A has a slower converage rate than estimator B (A may even not be consistent), but when $n$ is finite (properly), A has smaller MSE than B. I met this phenomenon in a complex simulation. I don't know if it happens by chance or it's common (I have tried many settings). So I wonder if there is some "simple" examples can provide intuition. Thanks again!

@whuber Thanks! This is a nice constructive proof. But are there any more "natural" examples? I mean, meaningful in practice. Thanks again!

I believe I have generated some fairly "natural" cases in the past where there's a swap-over at some small sample size, but I don't recall specific details right now. I'll see if I can come up with such a case again.  (Natural in the sense that someone might reasonably have chosen one or the other in practice.)

@Glen_b Thank you very much!

Well I found one but it's not quite satisfying to me yet; for samples from a $t_5$, median beats mean for small even sample sizes (n=4,6,8,...) and is beaten by the mean for small odd sample sizes (n=3,5,7,...); eventually the mean passes the median for all "large" sample sizes, but it takes a while. At $\nu=4$ it's similar but the median eventually wins there. I used simulations for this, but with pretty large simulation runs.  I expect I'll be able to find a better example. I'll try some more later. Ideally it would be good to have one that's less reliant on the median switching like that

@Glen As you likely know, the literature studying robust and non-parametric estimators is chock full of examples of such switching over.  In fact, just about any serious paper studying several alternative estimators will include simulations showing such effects and characterizing them.

For the negative binomial distribution with shape parameter not too large, method of moments performs better than MLE for smallish samples, but MLE wins out as the sample size gets large.

I think I have an example that I like well enough to post.
The estimators are nice and simple -- mean and median; I look only at odd sample sizes (which is the worse case for the median).
The density is that of the tails of a $t_{25}$ (the parts outside $(-1,1)$) "pushed together", so it's peaked in the middle and with somewhat heavier far tails than the normal. At small sample sizes the mean wins. At large sample sizes, the median does slightly better. Of course neither estimator of the center is efficient.
I'd like a simpler example for the density but this will do for now.
(A similar sort of example will do the same thing for even sample sizes where the median averages two points.)

